# Solidity question on transfers and hashing

Tags: hash, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

using solidity 8.16

from solidity:
TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 3 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use abi.encodePacked(...) to obtain the pre-0.5.0 behaviour or abi.encode(...) to use ABI encoding.
--> contract.sol:17:21:

```
function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players)); // bad line, trying to generate a sudo-random number and return the results
    }
```

from solidity:
TypeError: "send" and "transfer" are only available for objects of type "address payable", not "address".
--> contract.sol:22:18:

```
function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        payable (players[index].transfer(this).balance); <-- bad line trying to transfer funds of the contract to a address.
        players = new address[](0);
    }
```

I have been trying to figure this out for hours and idk what I'm doing wrong every time I fix what it say's it give me another error on the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, error message is clear. Use `abi.encodePacked`

```
  return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp, players,counter)));
```

For the second error, looks like you have `players` data structure. Since you are accessing with index, it must be an array that stores payable addresses.

```
 address payable[]  public players;
```

then to write the transfer logic:

```
players[index].transfer(address(this).balance);
```